# Apache2 disable 000-default.conf HTTPS redirect

Tags: https, apache2

I have a problem with my local Apache webserver. I've diabled and removed the `000-default.conf` file using the following commands as `root` user.

```
a2dissite /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

I've created this new `default.conf` file, that redirects HTTP requests to the HTTPS version:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally I've enabled the site and restarted the sever using:

```
a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

My problem is that my server does not apply the new settings. To me it seems as if it still uses the deleted `000-default.conf` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf        

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Here you are using wrong file name